# How do you set different web.config default error pages based on website section using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, web-config

I think this is pretty typical, you have the same website project with an "admin" section and a public facing section. In this website I want to configure the default errors, but I also want them to display in the correct layout. (the admin looks different than the public facing site).

In webforms you could put a different web.config in the the admin directory to take care of this, is there anyway to do it in MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the View (or Master) property of HandleErrorAttribute:

```
[HandleError(View="Foo")]
public ActionResult Bar(...
```